# Javascript - how to change/fix/sync system time for browser session

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, browser, clock

Let's say my website uses a 3rd party javascript library which requires the user's system time to be correct (synced with the server time) within a couple minutes.

Surprisingly many users have their device clocks set wrong by more than a couple minutes and are unable and/or unwilling to fix it. Is there any way I can fix it for them, at least inside a browser session?

I know how to get the correct time, but how can I "set" it into the browser session, so that it can be returned next time a 3rd party library asks for the current time?

For example, I would like to have something like this in my code:

```
let tWrong = new Date();   // contains wrong system time that the user has on their device
let tCorrect = getCorrectTimeFromServer();   // contains correct time fetched from a server
Date.someFunctionToSetGlobalTime(tCorrect);   // how to do this?
```

And then, somewhere deep in the 3rd party library where I do not have access to change the code, this would happen:

```
let t = new Date();   // t already contains the correct server time
```

And if this is not possible, how do websites normally deal with this issue? It must be incredibly common, for example when issuing JWT tokens with an expiry time, that one side thinks the token is already expired as soon as it is issued, due to wrong system time.

Comment: I don't think there's any standard way to set the clock in JS. You could monkey-patch all the `Date` methods to add an adjustment.

Comment: Most websites don't depend on clock synchronization. And the ones that do generally don't work if the user's clock isn't set correctly. I don't understand why most would have their clocks set wrong, since all popular operating systems have software to automatically sync using NTP. There's no excuse for being out of sync these days.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, in case someone runs into the same problem.

I found out the 3rd party library was using the `getUTCHours`, `getUTCMinutes` and `getUTCSeconds` functions, so instead of setting the time itself, I ended up overriding these functions like this. It feels ugly, but it works:

```
Date.prototype.getUTCHours = getMyCorrectUTCHours;
Date.prototype.getUTCMinutes = getMyCorrectUTCMinutes;
Date.prototype.getUTCSeconds = getMyCorrectUTCSeconds;
```